# Are there forum-like collaborative Q&A/Annotation tools out there?

Tags: teaching, collaboration, online-learning, distance-learning, website

I’m teaching an introductory programming course using the Moodle platform and I find that the forums are not used as extensively as they could be. Especially, students ask duplicated questions, have a hard time formatting their code correctly, and don't organise their questions and answers in a very structured way (e.g., they ask a new, unrelated question using the “Reply” button while reading another question).

I would be greatly interested in a web-based tool that would allow me to do this: divide my window vertically into two large columns. In the left column, I could post code snippets, my slides as PDFs, my exercises as PDF or HTML online, etc. In the right column, student could ask contextualised questions related to a particular line in the exercices or in the slides. The advantages would be:

- All previously asked questions related to this same point would already be shown on the left. This would considerably lower the the probability of duplicated questions.
- While asking a question, no need to copy and paste a code snippet to inform the reader about the context — the context is shown right there in the left column.
- A voting system similar to the StackExchange system would be great.

Are there any such tools out there?

Comment: See Stack Exchange Clones: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a shopping request. [softwarerecs.se] would be the right place to ask, but please follow [their guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/208/353).

Comment: While I appreciate that too many software requests would be irritating in the Academia forum, it is highly unlikely that education experts hang out in the Software Recommendations forum. I found the tag "Educational" with 14 posts, but very few are by instructors. If an instructor seeks a tool to aid instruction, this seems the best place to get experienced answers.

Comment: @Adrienne the community at [softwarerecs.se] has worked very hard on gathering and enforcing guidelines for both questions and answers that lead to those being useful for the OPs and for a much wider readership. They're the experts on doing this type of Q&A well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely my shortest answer ever. 
Check out NB (formerly "nota bene") via MIT
 http://nb.mit.edu/welcome

Instructors upload pdfs and students can highlight particular sections of it and ask questions.

Comment: NB is almost a perfect match! Thanks a lot for the link, Adrienne.